# Обратить человека в игрушку (см. контекст); можно не трогать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Так же гротескно выглядели все персонажи пьесы – за исключением самого
>   Печорина. Он был совершенно обыкновенен, отстранен, невыразителен,
>   откровенно скучен. Это злое его сердце, его желчь, его холодный
>   презрительный взгляд обращали всякого человека рядом с ним в нелепую
>   сломанную заводную игрушку.

(Спектакль по пьесе Нины Садур «Зовите Печориным».)

Если есть ещё какие огрехи - свистните, плииз!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же гротескно выглядели все персонажи пьесы – за исключением самого Печорина. Он был совершенно обыкновенен, **то есть** отстранен, невыразителен, откровенно скучен. Это злое его сердце, его желчь, его холодный презрительный взгляд обращали всякого человека  рядом с ним в **нелепую, сломанную** заводную игрушку.

Обыкновенен – как его играют обычно? Проверить однородность определений.

Comment: Жасмин, переписывать автора НЕЛЬЗЯ!!! Скоро приглашу на сайт актрисы, но там ещё будут недоработки, потому что компьютер не предполагает процесс сверки, абсолютно необходимой технологически, т. е. я не вижу, без новых ошибок автор внёс правку или, меняя под нашим нажимом что-то на свой лад, нарисовал новые...

Comment: Я не предлагаю ничего менять, просто указываю на те места, которые трудно понимаются. Лично я не поняла,  как автор оценивает игру Печорина - хвалит, ругает, просто выделяет его игру как обычную, без гротеска. Но, наверное,  смысл текста проверять не надо, только грамматику  и стиль.

Comment: По-моему, автор мыслит нечетко, потому и излагает неясно.

Comment: Автор полшкольной жизни проснимался в синематографе: упущенный русский! Но мыслит вполне чётко.

Comment: Второе предложение автор противопоставляет первому (поясняя, что хотелось бы видеть) или раскрывает им "обыкновенность" через скукоту "злого сердца"?